# How to display only configurable products count in the catalog?

Tags: magento2, catalog

I set to show only configurable products on my catalog. The problem is the product count displayed in the product list toolbar. It shows total count of simple products not configurable what I think is more important for the customer. How to display "correct" count?
[image]